# closed linear span of $\{ e_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ in $l^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

If $A=\{ e_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ where $e_n$ is a sequence whose $n$<sup>th</sup> term is $1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then I need to find the smallest closed linear subspace in $l^{\infty}$ that contains $A$.

I think $c_0$ is the answer.

My attempt:

I  proved that $c_0$ is a closed linear subspace that containing $A$ and this proves one containment, but I couldn't prove that $c_0 \subset \bigcap_{A\subset E_i}{E_i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)\in c_0$, then let

- $x_1=(a_1,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$;
- $x_2=(a_1,a_2,0,0,0,\ldots)$;
- $x_3=(a_1,a_2,a_3,0,0,\ldots)$

and so on. Then $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ (and, in order to prove this, the fact that $x\in c_0$ is essential) and each $x_n$ belongs to$$\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{e_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\bigr).\tag1$$Therefore every closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$ that contains $(1)$ also contains $c_0$. So, $c_0$ is indeed the smallest closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$ which contains $(1)$.

Comment: Carlos Santos, can you please help prove that $x \in c_0$? It seems there are  cases

Comment: That request makes no sense. I am **assuming** that $x\in c_0$. Do you want me to **deduce** from that that $x\in c_0$?

Comment: Or do you want me to prove that $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$?

Comment: My apologies! I mean proving $x = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n $?

Comment: Take $\varepsilon>0$. Now take $\varepsilon'>0$ such that $\varepsilon'<\varepsilon$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n>N\implies|a_n|<\varepsilon'$. So,$$n\geqslant N\implies\|x-x_n\|_\infty=\sup_{k>n}|a_k|\leqslant\varepsilon'<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!
But, $\sup$ in the last line should be over $ k >N$, right?

Comment: No. I am dealing here with $x-x_n$ here, not $x-x_N$.

Comment: You are right! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sir, can we guess the smallest closed subspace that containing $A=\{1,x,x^2, \cdots \}$ in $(C[0,1], ||.||_\{infty})$ ?
I want to answer by set of all polynomials in $[0,1]$ but I know it is not closed subspace.

Comment: It's $C([0,1])$ itself, by the Stone-WWeierstrass theorem.

Comment: can we prove the guess without this theorem, just working on sequences?
For instance, the sequence of $(\sum_{k=0}^n{x^k/k!})$ which converges to $e^x$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I don't think so.